# how to create additional button on single product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I can Create Additional Custom Button on single product page with following feature. 1st- my button work with product Attribute. if attribute id is "`custom_button`" value is "`yes`" then show custom button on signal product page and if value is "`no`" button hidden on product page. 2nd- custom button name is attribute id "`custom_button_name`" value = `Button Text`. 3rd- custom button url is attribute id "`custom_button_url`" value = "`http://www.websiteurl.com`"when click on button open new tab

i have create custom button on magento site with following code. this code work with product attributes how to use this code in woocommerce

```
<?php if($_product->getCustom_button()){ //yes or no button?>

<button type="button" title="<?php echo $_product>getCustom_button_name() ;?>"

class="action primary tocart"

onclick="window.open('<?php echo $_product>getCustom_button_url() ;?>')">

<span><span><i class="icon-desktop"></i>

<?php echo $_product->getCustom_button_name() ;?></span></span>

</button>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

To achieve something like this you should change the `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item` hook, which is where the add to cart button is added.

To replace it with custom behavior, first, you remove the button, then add your custom button in its place.

```
add_action( 'init', 'remove_add_to_cart_button' );
function remove_add_to_cart_button() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'new_add_to_cart_button' );
function new_add_to_cart_button() {
    // Your button code.
}
```

You can find more about WooCommerce hooks here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html.